# Uploading a document to a SP 2010 server via VB6

Tags: web-services, vba

I'm currently trying to upload a file to a SharePoint 2010 server from within a VB6 application. Unfortunately I can't use any .NET or other additional libraries.

I've read a couple of suggestions for this task such as using an HTTP PUT request [(ref)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd902097%28v=office.12%29.aspx). **Note**: The page shows SP 2007 documentation and I can't find any information on whether this is still possible or not. The only documentaton I could find was [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479623.aspx) rather cryptic documentation of a 'put document' method (unfortunately without any examples).

I was hoping that it was possible to use the REST service for this task, but it seems like uploading documents via the REST interface is not supported in SP2010 (at least I couldn't find any documentation for this feature).

The last option that I'm currently looking into is using the Copy.asmx web service. While this *should* be working, I think this would require to make some (in my opinion) unpleasant design choices (such as using yet another type of WS in a rather small application, having to create/read an XML request in code and having to use base64 encoding).

I was hoping that one of you guys has made some experiences in this area and could shed some light on which alternative could be the best (i.e. simplest) solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [SOAP Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286526.aspx) to have the VB6 client make the SharePoint asmx web service calls (using Copy.asmx to upload files) - this MSDN post gives more details

[Migrating from the SOAP Toolkit to Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973876.aspx)